# Failling to reorder tableView cell images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, completionhandler, dispatch-async

For study purposes, I'm creating a app to show a list of some star wars ships. It fetches my json (locally) for the ship objects (it has 4 ships for this example).
It's using a custom cell for the table view.

The table populates without problems, if I already have the images downloaded (in user documents) or not.
My starshipData array is populated by my DataManager class by delegate.
I removed some code to make the class smaller, I can show everything if needed.

Ok, so the problem happens (very rarely) when I press the sorting button.
The way I'm doing it is after recovering or downloading the image, I update the image field in starshipData array.

Here is my sorting method, pretty basic.

```
@objc private func sortByCost(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        starshipData.sort { $0.costInCredits < $1.costInCredits }
        starshipTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here are the implementations of the tableView.

First I use the **cellForRowAt** method to populate the fast/light data.

```
    // MARK: -> cellForRowAt
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StarshipCell", for: indexPath) as! StarshipCell
        let starship = starshipData[indexPath.row]
        
        // update cell properties
        cell.starshipNameLabel.text = starship.name
        cell.starshipManufacturerLabel.text = starship.manufacturer
        cell.starshipCostLabel.text = currencyFormatter(value: starship.costInCredits)

        // only populate the image if the array has one (the first time the table is populated, 
        // the array doesn't have an image, it'll need to download or fetch it in user documents) 
        if starship.image != nil {
            cell.starshipImgView.image = starship.image
        }
        
        // adds right arrow indicator on the cell
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        
        return cell
    }
```

Here I use the **willDisplay** method to download or fetch the images, basically the heavier data.

```
    // MARK: -> willDisplay
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // update cell image
        let cell = cell as! StarshipCell
        let imageUrl = starshipData[indexPath.row].imageUrl
        let starshipName = starshipData[indexPath.row].name
        let index = indexPath.row
        
        // if there isn't any image on the cell, proceed to manage the image
        if cell.starshipImgView.image == nil {
            // only instantiate spinner on imageView position if no images are set
            let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
            startSpinner(spinner: spinner, cell: cell)

            // manage the image
            imageManager(starshipName: starshipName, imageUrl: imageUrl, spinner: spinner, cell: cell, index: index) { (image) in
                self.addImageToCell(cell: cell, spinner: spinner, image: image)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is where I think the problem is as my knowledge in swift and background threads are still in development.

I found out with print logs that the times the cell doesn't show the correct image is because the array does not have the image for that index, so the cell shows the image from the last time the table was populated/loaded.

I wonder if it's because the background threads didn't have enough time to update the starshipArray with the fetched/downloaded image before the user pushing the sort button.

The thing is, if the table was populated correctly the first time, when the sort button is pushed, the starshipData array should already have all images, as you can see in the imageManager method, after the image is unwrappedFromDocuments, I call updateArrayImage to update the image.

Maybe it's the amount of dispatchesQueues being used? Are the completion handler and dispatchQueues used correctly?

```
    private func imageManager(starshipName: String, imageUrl: URL?, spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView, cell: StarshipCell, index: Int, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        // if json has a string on image_url value
        if let unwrappedImageUrl = imageUrl {
            // open a background thread to prevent ui freeze
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                // tries to retrieve the image from documents folder
                let imageFromDocuments = self.retrieveImage(imageName: starshipName)
                
                // if image was retrieved from folder, upload it
                if let unwrappedImageFromDocuments = imageFromDocuments {


// TO FORCE THE PROBLEM DESCRIBED, PREVENT ONE SHIP TO HAVE IT'S IMAGE UPDATED
//                    if (starshipName != "Star Destroyer") { 
                        self.updateArrayImage(index: index, image: unwrappedImageFromDocuments)
//                    }
                    
                    completion(unwrappedImageFromDocuments)
                }
                    // if image wasn't retrieved or doesn't exists, try to download from the internet
                else {
                    var image: UIImage?
                    self.downloadManager(imageUrl: unwrappedImageUrl) { data in
                        // if download was successful
                        if let unwrappedData = data {
                            // convert image data to image
                            image = UIImage(data: unwrappedData)
                            if let unwrappedImage = image {
                                self.updateArrayImage(index: index, image: unwrappedImage)
                                // save images locally on user documents folder so it can be used whenever it's needed
                                self.storeImage(image: unwrappedImage, imageName: starshipName)
                                completion(unwrappedImage)
                            }
                        }
                            // if download was not successful
                        else {
                            self.addImageNotFound(spinner: spinner, cell: cell)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            // if json has null on image_url value
        else {
            addImageNotFound(spinner: spinner, cell: cell)
        }
    }
```

Here are some of the helper methods I use on imageManager, if necessary.

```
// MARK: - Helper Methods
    private func updateArrayImage(index: Int, image: UIImage) {
        // save image in the array so it can be used when cells are sorted
        self.starshipData[index].image = image
    }
    
    private func downloadManager(imageUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        let session: URLSession = {
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
            return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        }()
        
        var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
        dataTask?.cancel()
        dataTask = session.dataTask(with: imageUrl) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            defer {
                dataTask = nil
            }
            if let error = error {
                // use error if necessary
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
            else if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode != 200 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
            else if let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200 { // Ok response
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(data)
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
    
    private func addImageNotFound(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView, cell: StarshipCell) {
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        cell.starshipImgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ImageNotFound")
    }
    
    private func addImageToCell(cell: StarshipCell, spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView, image: UIImage) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            cell.starshipImgView.image = image
        }
    }
    
    private func imagePath(imageName: String) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        // path to save the images on documents directory
        guard let documentPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                  in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        let appendedDocumentPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        return appendedDocumentPath
    }
    
    private func retrieveImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let imagePath = self.imagePath(imageName: imageName),
            let imageData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: imagePath.path),
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func storeImage(image: UIImage, imageName: String) {
        if let jpgRepresentation = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
            if let imagePath = self.imagePath(imageName: imageName) {
                do  {
                    try jpgRepresentation.write(to: imagePath,
                                                options: .atomic)
                } catch let err {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func startSpinner(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView, cell: StarshipCell) {
        spinner.center = cell.starshipImgView.center
        cell.starshipContentView.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
    }
    
}
```

To sum all up, here is the unordered table, when you open the app: [unordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bag3W.jpg)

The expected result (happens majority of time), after pushing the sort button: [ordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01yRw.jpg)

The wrong result (rarely happens), after pushing the sort button: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgnEQ.jpg)

I'll gladly add more info if needed, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider move the cell configuration for the UITableViewCell class. something like this:

```
class StarshipCell {

    private var starshipNameLabel = UILabel()
    private var starshipImgView = UIImageView()

    func configure(with model: Starship) {
       starshipNameLabel.text = model.name
       starshipImgView.downloadedFrom(link: model.imageUrl)
    }
}
```

Call the `configure(with: Starship)` method in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:).`

The method `downloadedFrom(link: )` called inside the `configure(with: Starship)` is provide by following extension

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func downloadedFrom(link: String?, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        if let link = link {
            guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
            downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have a question. 
Calling configure inside the cellForRowAt method will make so every cell will have the image downloaded even if they are not being shown. Is that what will happen?
I know I only have 4 ships in this example, but I was wondering what would happen if there were 1000 for example.

Another thing, can you tell me what I did wrong on my example? I'm wondering if using willDisplay method was wrong.

Comment: - the method `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:).` is called only when cell will appear. Thefore,  if you have 1000 elements you don't have a 1000 images in memory.

- particulary I have never use the method willDisplay. I read the documentation, but it is a quiet confused. I recomend that you don't use willDisplay for this purpose. I'm sory for don't know any exemple in mind. 
Finaly you can read this post https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e that clarify how table view works. 

Please if this resolve your question, mark the answer as solution.

Comment: hi friend, I was taking some time to test things out.
yes, your examples seemed to fix the problem, i'll mark as a solution.

I tried as well moving the willDisplay code to the cellForRowAt method, I added more objects in my json, and even tried to add/remove some dispatchqueues on other specific locations, a lot of testing going on. 

I'm still making sure everything is smooth and I'm following some guides on how to do it.
Thank you for the help!